# Adding two elements side by side, responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website, but I stack to a point and I can't figure out how to solve it.
I am using [this](https://github.com/yairEO/fancyInput) open source code to make my input looks fancy.

I am trying to make a small difference on it, but won't work. I want to add at the right of the fancy textbox a text. The textbox have min-width and max-width, so while typing the textbox is expanded. If I do positioning using margin-left then, when the textbox resized to bigger, the textbox will get over the text.

first css:

```
html{ height:100%; min-width:600px; height:100%; }
body{ height:100%; text-align:center; background:-webkit-radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742); background:radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742);}
#wrap{ min-width:600px; height:100%; position:relative; background:-webkit-radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742); background:radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742); overflow:hidden; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Fjalla One'), local('FjallaOne-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/fjallaone/v1/rxxXUYj4oZ6Q5oDJFtEd6hsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Fjalla One'), local('FjallaOne-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/fjallaone/v1/rxxXUYj4oZ6Q5oDJFtEd6hsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
  position: relative;
  color:white;
  font-size: 53px;

}

*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

/* body::before{ content:''; display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; } */
header{ position:absolute; z-index:999; top:0; left:0; width:100%; padding:10px 0; text-align:center; }
    header menu{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; overflow:hidden; margin:0 12px; border-radius:6px; box-shadow:0 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); }
        header menu button{ font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif; margin:0; cursor:pointer; color:#333; padding:6px 12px; text-shadow:0 1px #DDD; font-size:.9em; float:left; border:0; border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); box-shadow:0 -20px 20px -20px #777 inset; -webkit-transition:.1s; transition:.1s; }
        header menu button:hover{ background-color:#CCC; }
        header menu button:first-child{ border:0; }
        header menu button.active{ background-color:#BBB; color:#000; box-shadow:0 1px 3px #111 inset; padding:7px 12px 6px; }

        menu.radio{ background:#EEE; box-shadow:0 -20px 20px -20px #666 inset, 0 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2); position:relative; }
            menu.radio > div{ position:absolute; top:2px; bottom:2px; border-radius:5px; left:0; z-index:1; background:#103555; box-shadow:0 16px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset; -webkit-transition:0.2s ease-out; transition:0.2s ease-out; }
            menu.radio label{ display:inline-block; position:relative; z-index:2; margin:0 2px; }
            menu.radio span{ opacity:.5; color:#222; font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif; cursor:pointer; padding:6px 12px; display:inline-block; -webkit-transition:0.2s ease-out; transition:0.2s ease-out; }
            menu.radio :checked ~ span{ opacity:1; color:#FFF; }
            menu.radio label:hover span{ opacity:1; }
            menu.radio input{ display:none; }

    a.git, a.by{ position:absolute; bottom:2px; right:5px; -webkit-transform:scale(0.8); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%; transform:scale(0.8); transform-origin:100% 100%; opacity:0.3; -webkit-transition:0.3s cubic-bezier(0.055, 0.6, 0.2, 1); transition:0.3s cubic-bezier(0.055, 0.6, 0.2, 1); }
    a.git:hover, a.by:hover{ -webkit-transform:scale(1); transform:scale(1); opacity:1; }
        a.git img{  }

    a.by{ text-transform:capitalize; right:auto; left:5px; font-size:20px; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif; -webkit-transform-origin:0% 100%; transform-origin:0% 100%; }
    .social{ position:absolute; top:-15px; left:5px; -webkit-filter:blur(20px); opacity:0; -webkit-transition:1s ease-out; transition:.6s ease-out; }
    .social.show{ top:5px; opacity:1; -webkit-filter:none; }
    .fbLike{ height:21px; width:100px; border:none; }
    .twitter-share-button{  }
    .social > *{ opacity:.5; -webkit-transition:.2s ease-out; transition:.2s ease-out;  }
    .social > *:hover{ opacity:1; }

#content{ position:absolute; width:200%; height:100%; -webkit-transition:.6s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.6, 0.2, 1); transition:.6s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.6, 0.2, 1); }
    #content section{ width:50%; height:100%; float:left; }
    #content section::before{ content:''; display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; }

.fancyInput{ max-width:20%; min-width:8%; font-size:40px; color:#FFF; vertical-align:middle; line-height:1.3; overflow:hidden; text-align:left; box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset, 0 0 12px rgba(255,255,255,.1); padding:8px 20px; background:rgba(0,0,0,.1); border-radius:10px; }
```

second css:

```
@charset "IBM437";
@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
    transform: scaleY(0.8); } }

@-webkit-keyframes caret {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.8); } }

.fancyInput {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  /* only Caret which is  */
  /* lettes */
  /*.fancyInput > div span:last-of-type ~ br{ display:block; white-space:pre; }*/
  /*.fancyInput br:last-of-type + .caret{ position:static; display:inline-block; }*/
  /* text effects */ }
  .fancyInput ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent; }
  .fancyInput :-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent; }
  .fancyInput ::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent; }
  .fancyInput :-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent; }
  .fancyInput.textarea {
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: auto; }
  .fancyInput input, .fancyInput textarea {
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: none;
    padding: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif;
    font-size: inherit;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
  .fancyInput input {
    top: 1px;
    left: -1px;
    padding-right: 0; }
  .fancyInput textarea {
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; }
  .fancyInput > div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
    .fancyInput > div:before {
      opacity: 0;
      left: -20px;
      content: attr(data-placeholder);
      position: absolute;
      transition: 0.3s ease-out; }
    .fancyInput > div.empty:before {
      opacity: 0.2;
      left: 0; }
  .fancyInput input:focus ~ div.empty:before {
    opacity: .1; }
  .fancyInput.textarea > div {
    width: 99.9%%; }
  .fancyInput *:focus ~ .caret,
  .fancyInput *:focus ~ div .caret {
    opacity: .8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFF;
    -webkit-animation: 0.4s 40ms caret infinite;
    animation: 0.4s 40ms caret infinite; }
  .fancyInput .caret {
    font-weight: normal;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-user-select: none; }
  .fancyInput span:not(.deleted) ~ .caret {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0; }
  .fancyInput > div span {
    -webkit-transition: 100ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.6, 0.55, 1.4);
    transition: 100ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.6, 0.55, 1.4);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
  .fancyInput > input[type=password] + div span:empty::after {
    content: '●';
    display: inline; }
  .fancyInput > div .deleted {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 140ms;
    transition: 140ms;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(12px);
    transform: translateX(12px); }
  .fancyInput > div span.state1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: translateY(-25px) rotateX(90deg); }
  .fancyInput > div span.state2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(25px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: translateY(25px) rotateX(90deg); }

/* DEMO text effects */
.effect2 .fancyInput > div span.state1, .effect2 .fancyInput > div span.state2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(10px) scale(1.8);
  transform: translateX(10px) scale(1.8); }

.effect3 .fancyInput > div span {
  -webkit-transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.6, 0.55, 1.4);
  transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.6, 0.55, 1.4); }
  .effect3 .fancyInput > div span.state1, .effect3 .fancyInput > div span.state2 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px); }

.effect4 .fancyInput > div span {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-duration: 150ms; }
  .effect4 .fancyInput > div span.state1, .effect4 .fancyInput > div span.state2 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    transform: translateY(-60px); }

.effect5 .fancyInput > div span {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-duration: 150ms; }
  .effect5 .fancyInput > div span.state1, .effect5 .fancyInput > div span.state2 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
    transform: translateX(-30px);
    opacity: 0; }
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5amwgn/) code.

I need a method, that will put the text heading at the right of the textbox, but responsively so that when the textbox goes bigger, also the text heading also move to the right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this kinda what you were looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/brsd11/rnwe0mps/

**HTML**

```
div id='wrap'>
    <div id='content'>
        <section class='input'>
            <div>
               <input id='inputID' type='text' placeholder='enter'/>
            </div>
            <label for='inputID' class='custom'>Test Header</label>
        </section>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label.custom{
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  display:inline;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Just to understand what you did. How this works? can you expand the commands to explanation?